# Can hooking up battery cables incorrectly ruin the throttle body in a 2007 Toyota XLE V6

Tags: toyota, camry, throttle-body

Can hooking up jumper cables incorrectly on a 2007 Toyota Camry XLe V6 affect the throttle body?  After I did my car would not go over 25 mph. My mechanic put it on the tester for the code and told me that it would need a throttlebody.  It didn't take him more than a half hour to fix and cost $1258. He said what I did ruin the throttlebody and that was tied in with the computer of the car.

Comment: That's a very broad question. Is there something specific that you're wondering about? Describe what the car is doing. That will help you get useful responses.

Answer (score 2):

Hooking up backwards on Toyota of that era would blow multiple fuses including some in the main fuse block, the long strip fuse in the underhood box with a clear plastic cover. A common symptom was that the engine could start but not accelerate and would set codes for the throttle body. I have not seen one that damaged the throttle unit, but it is not impossible.

The first step in testing after a backward jump is to remove and inspect the main fuse block, replace as needed. Replace any of the other fuses that have blown. Clear any codes and retest. If certain codes are set PCM will stay in fail-safe mode causing a power limit.